# How to fill a fxml Tableview from controller class

Tags: javafx, fxml

I want to fill TableView with data in controller but I don't know why my solution doesn't work.

in fxml the element I want to fill, looks like this:

```
      <TableView fx:id="t" layoutX="0" layoutY="30" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="600">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="200" text="name" fx:id="name" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="200" text="adress" fx:id="adress" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="200" text="phone" fx:id="phone" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
```

and my Controler :

```
public class controler implements  Initializable  {
    public Pane p;
    public MenuBar menu;
    @FXML public TableView<User> t;
    @FXML public TableColumn<User, String> name;
    @FXML public TableColumn<User, String> adress;
    @FXML public TableColumn<User, String> phone;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(new User("zaza","zaza","zaza"));
          menu.prefWidthProperty().bind(p.widthProperty());
          t.getItems().add(new User("John","NewYork","+16879060"));
          t.setEditable(true);
          t.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I am trying to add some data to the table but the the table shows empty colums i don't know where is the mistake

My User model which i suppose it's perfect:

```
public class User {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty adress;
    private SimpleStringProperty phone;

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public void setName(SimpleStringProperty name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAdress() {
        return adress.get();
    }
    public void setAdress(SimpleStringProperty adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone.get();
    }
    public void setPhone(SimpleStringProperty phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public User(String name, String adress, String phone) {
        super();
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.adress = new SimpleStringProperty(adress);
        this.phone = new SimpleStringProperty(phone);
    }

}
```

The results : 
 [image]

Comment: [mcve] please (you are near, the missing the complete fxml and the application :) That said: from your snippets it looks like you don't configure the column with a cellValueFactory. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. Oh just seeing: the api of your data class is pathological - have a look at a tutorial/course book and see the conventional way of accessing properties and their values (hint: typically they are _not_ passed as parameters)

Comment: Hi @Ramprasath Selvam thank you for your reply ,i am new to javafx and fxml and English is not my mother tong ,can you suggest any tuto/course to learn the basics

Comment: @yassine Have a look at this link https://riptutorial.com/ebook/javafx

Comment: Grendel ,thank you very much that was exactly what i am looking for.